# How to get application name on various Android device?

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

I am using bellow code to get application name in Android. For example on Galaxy S4; if the phone is in `Home screen`, and the below function returns the `TouchWiz home`. However,  on Note 4, the function returns `Google Home`. Do we have any way to maintain the application name or detect the name depending on the device name? Currently, I save the `Home screen` in a list corresponding to the device name. However, I think it will not cover all possible case.

```
public String getAppName() {
        String foregroundProcess = "";
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {                                
            UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time); 
            // Sort the stats by the last time used
            if (stats != null) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                }
                if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    String topPackageName = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                    foregroundProcess = topPackageName;
                }
            }
        } else {                                                                                    
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
            foregroundProcess = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
        }

        //Convert package name to application name
        final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo ai;
        try {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(foregroundProcess, 0);
        } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            ai = null;
        }
        String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");       

        return applicationName;
    }
```

Comment: But what you wana achive? Why did't you search for proper intent filters in manifests?

Comment: I want to achieve the application name of home screen. The issue is the application name is various among devices.

Comment: Home screen activity has category HOME, and action MAIN .... you can search all activities with those filter ...

Comment: I know the activity to achieve it. I want to get the name of this, instead of go to that

Comment: you know that users can change the default launcher right ?